# %dopar% in R does not work properly when try to use parallel

Tags: r, parallel.foreach, doparallel

### %dopar% in R does not work properly when try to use parallel

First,I'm sorry that my english is not good,only in stackoverflow i found similar questions but cant understand how to deal :(

Here is my original code:

```
library(cramer)
n<-50
theta<-seq(-2,2,0.2)
ks<-rep(0,21)
cvm<-rep(0,21)
ks2<-rep(0,21)
cvm2<-rep(0,21)
for (k in 1:21) {
  for (i in 1:5) {
    X<-runif(n)
    Y<-runif(n,min=0,max=1/(1+theta[k]/sqrt(10)))
    ks[k]<-ks[k]+(ks.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    cvm[k]<-cvm[k]+(cramer.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    ks2[k]<-ks2[k]+(ks.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    cvm2[k]<-cvm2[k]+(cramer.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
  }
}

ks<-ks
cvm<-cvm
ks2<-ks2
cvm2<-cvm2
```

When it's done ,we can find that the values changed like this

```
> ks
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5
> cvm
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 5
> ks2
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 4 5 5 5 5 5
> cvm2
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 1 2 1 0 1 1 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

For speed up my calculate ,i try to use foreach ,so  the new code i try is :

```
library("cramer")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")

n<-50
theta<-seq(-2,2,0.2)
ks<-rep(0,21)
cvm<-rep(0,21)
ks2<-rep(0,21)
cvm2<-rep(0,21)

cl<-parallel::makeCluster(5,outfile="debug.txt")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach (k = 1:21,.combine =list,.multicombine = TRUE,.inorder=TRUE,.packages = "cramer") %dopar% {
   cat("start to calculate \n", file = paste0("debug_file_", k, ".txt"))

 for (i in 1:6)  {
    cat("It's the ",k,"progress","now the runtimes is ",i,"\n", file = paste0("debug_file_", k, ".txt"),append=T)
    X<-runif(n)
    cat("X is",ks[k],"\n", file = paste0("debug_file_", k, ".txt"),append=T)
    Y<-runif(n,min=0,max=1/(1+theta[k]/sqrt(10)))
    ks[k]<-ks[k]+(ks.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    cat("ks- ",k,"is",ks[k],"\n", file = paste0("debug_file_", k, ".txt"),append=T)
    cvm[k]<-cvm[k]+(cramer.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    ks2[k]<-ks2[k]+(ks.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    cvm2[k]<-cvm2[k]+(cramer.test(X,Y)$p.value<=0.05)
    cat("cvm2- ",k,"is",cvm2[k],"\n", file = paste0("debug_file_", k, ".txt"),append=T)
  }
  }

ks
cvm
ks2
cvm2

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Through the cpu & debug files i guess the calculate parallel is worked ,but can't write the value correctly.

```
> ks
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> cvm
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ks2
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> cvm2
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I have found many informantion ,guess it's because the parallel copy the date in different cluster,but don't know how to fix my code.

---

my question is long, thx for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ks[k] <- ...` won't actually modify the `ks` variable outside of the `foreach`. Modify the `foreach` to combine all of the values into a data frame.

```
library("cramer")
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")

n <- 50
theta <- seq(-2, 2, 0.2)

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(5, outfile = "debug.txt")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach (k = 1:21, .combine = rbind, .multicombine = TRUE, .inorder=TRUE, .packages = "cramer") %dopar% {
  ks <- 0
  cvm <- 0
  ks2 <- 0
  cvm2 <- 0
  
  for (i in 1:5)  {
    X <- runif(n)
    Y <- runif(n, min = 0, max = 1 / (1 + theta[k] / sqrt(10)))
    ks <- ks + (ks.test(X, Y)$p.value <= 0.05)
    cvm <- cvm + (cramer.test(X, Y)$p.value <= 0.05)
    ks2 <- ks2 + (ks.test(X, Y)$p.value <= 0.05)
    cvm2 <- cvm2 + (cramer.test(X, Y)$p.value <= 0.05)
  }
  
  data.frame(
    ks = ks,
    cvm = cvm,
    ks2 = ks2,
    cvm2 = cvm2
  )
}
#>    ks cvm ks2 cvm2
#> 1   5   5   5    5
#> 2   5   5   5    5
#> 3   5   5   5    5
#> 4   5   5   5    5
#> 5   5   5   5    5
#> 6   5   5   5    5
#> 7   3   3   3    3
#> 8   1   1   1    1
#> 9   1   1   1    1
#> 10  0   1   0    1
#> 11  2   0   2    0
#> 12  1   3   1    3
#> 13  0   0   0    0
#> 14  1   1   1    1
#> 15  2   3   2    3
#> 16  3   3   3    3
#> 17  4   4   4    4
#> 18  3   3   3    3
#> 19  4   4   4    4
#> 20  5   5   5    5
#> 21  5   5   5    5

parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```